# Combine setValue to one setValues call using a range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In simplest terms, I am setting these cells to these values.  The code below works.

I want to rewrite it so that I make only a single setValues call instead, to hopefully save time (I'm over my 30 second limit).

```
function otherfunction()
{
// getting templateSS and stuff
...
    var amshottimesrc = new Date();";
        copiedfromtemplate = templateSS.getSheetByName(sheetchoice).copyTo(memberSS);
            copiedfromtemplate.getRange("B5").setValue(addMinutes(amshottimesrc,-30));
            copiedfromtemplate.getRange("D5").setValue(addMinutes(amshottimesrc,60));
            copiedfromtemplate.getRange("E5").setValue(addMinutes(amshottimesrc,60*2));
            copiedfromtemplate.getRange("F5").setValue(addMinutes(amshottimesrc,60*3));
            copiedfromtemplate.getRange("G5").setValue(addMinutes(amshottimesrc,60*4));
            copiedfromtemplate.getRange("H5").setValue(addMinutes(amshottimesrc,60*5));
            copiedfromtemplate.getRange("I5").setValue(addMinutes(amshottimesrc,60*6));
            copiedfromtemplate.getRange("J5").setValue(addMinutes(amshottimesrc,60*7));
}


function addMinutes(date, minutes) {
    return new Date(date.getTime() + minutes*60000);
}
```

I've tried literally every combination of everything I could come up with with arrays and ranges and syntax literally all day and I think I'm going crazy.  Help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `I want to rewrite it so that I make only a single setValues call instead`, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
copiedfromtemplate.getRange("B5").setValue(addMinutes(amshottimesrc,-30));
copiedfromtemplate.getRange("D5").setValue(addMinutes(amshottimesrc,60));
copiedfromtemplate.getRange("E5").setValue(addMinutes(amshottimesrc,60*2));
copiedfromtemplate.getRange("F5").setValue(addMinutes(amshottimesrc,60*3));
copiedfromtemplate.getRange("G5").setValue(addMinutes(amshottimesrc,60*4));
copiedfromtemplate.getRange("H5").setValue(addMinutes(amshottimesrc,60*5));
copiedfromtemplate.getRange("I5").setValue(addMinutes(amshottimesrc,60*6));
copiedfromtemplate.getRange("J5").setValue(addMinutes(amshottimesrc,60*7));
```

#### To:

In this modification, it supposes that the cell "C5" has already had a value.

```
var range1 = copiedfromtemplate.getRange("B5:J5");
var value1 = range1.getValues()[0];
var ar = [-30, null, 60, 60 * 2, 60 * 3, 60 * 4, 60 * 5, 60 * 6, 60 * 7];
var res = [ar.map((e, i) => e ? addMinutes(amshottimesrc, e) : value1[i])];
range1.setValues(res);
```

If the cell "C5" is empty, I think that you can also use the following modification.

```
var ar = [-30, null, 60, 60 * 2, 60 * 3, 60 * 4, 60 * 5, 60 * 6, 60 * 7];
var res = [ar.map(e => e ? addMinutes(amshottimesrc, e) : null)];
copiedfromtemplate.getRange("B5:J5").setValues(res);
```

#### Note:

- I cannot understand the situation of `I'm over my 30 second limit`. But, when I saw your showing script, I'm worried that the script with the high process cost might be existing other script. If this didn't obtain your expected result, can you provide your whole script?

#### Reference:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: YOU ARE MY HERO!!!!!  I will come back if that doesn't speed things up.  TY!!!

Comment: @Dan Y. Thank you for replying. When this modification was useful, I'm glad.

Comment: @Dan Y. Thank you for replying. About `still having an issue (with my inability to understand datetimes in app script mostly)`, this is differrent from your question. So, can you post it as a new question by including more information? By this, it will help users including me think of a solution. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: Ok I'm still having some trouble (this time with my general inability to grasp datetimes and time zones). 

It's incrementally filling perfectly - except appears to be a different time zone than C5.

The form field is actually only a time (like 11:00).  I was getting it with
```
      var amshottime = formrespsheet.getRange(amshottimesource).getDisplayValue(); 
```
(so a string)

Is there a proper way to convert the hh:mm value so it will retain the current hour so I can use it as amshottimesrc ?  When I set it as a new Date, it changes the time.

Comment: @Dan Y. Thank you for replying. If you cannot understand my English. Please tell me. About `still having an issue (with my inability to understand datetimes in app script mostly)`, this is different from your question. But, I would like to support you. So, can you post it as a new question by including more information? By this, it will help users including me think of a solution. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?